# Calculate the sum of property

Tags: c#

I'm trying to calculate the sum of the property name called `Total` to `GrandTotal`. What I want it to do is that `GrandTotal` calculates the sum of all `Total`, this is how I tried it:

```
public class ItemProperties
        {
            public int Item { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
            public int UnitPrice { get; set; }
            public int Tax { get; set; }
            public int TotalTax { get { return ((Quantity * UnitPrice) * Tax) /100 ; } }
            public int Total { get { return (Quantity * UnitPrice) + TotalTax; } }

            public int GrandTotal
            {
                get
                {
                    foreach (var l in Total) //Error
                        l += Total;          // Error
                    return l;                //Error
                }
            }
        }
```

The class `ItemProperties` is added with the `Add()` method two times likes this:
(So `Total` is having a different values with each add)

```
 Items.Add(new ItemProperties {
    Item = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i]),
    Description = lines[i + 1],
    Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i + 2]),
    UnitPrice = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i + 3]),
    Tax = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i + 4])
});
Items.Add(new ItemProperties {
    Item = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i + 5]),
    Description = lines[i + 6],
    Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i + 7]),
    UnitPrice = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i + 8]),
    Tax = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i + 9])
});
```

Don't worry about the `lines` variables, they're not relevant..
The only thing I want is that the `GrandTotal` calculate the sum of all Total properties.

Comment: In your GrantTotal property, you are trying to loop through an integer instead of the enumerable. You should create an extension to your items.

Comment: What do you mean "total of single property"? Usually "total" is computed over collection of some sort, usually with something like `items.Sum(i => i.Property)`

Comment: It's odd that GrandTotal is on the same level as Total. Logically it would make sense to be a level higher, so you can get the total from your collection of items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot execute a `foreach` on something that is not enumerable - and your `Total` property is an `int`, not an IEnumerable.

Your `GrandTotal` property should probably be in the class that contains the collection of `ItemProperties`, your code would look something similar to this:

```
public ItemProperties[] MyItems { get; set; }

public int GrandTotal 
{
    get 
    {
        var total = 0;
        foreach (var item in MyItems)
            total += item.Total;

        return total;
    }
}
```

Or if you wanted to use LINQ:

```
public List<ItemProperties> MyItems { get; set; }

public int GrandTotal 
{
    get {  return MyItems.Sum(item => item.Total); }
}
```

Note that I've kept this simple and not included any null checking code etc - that's an exercise for you to complete.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Do you have any tips on how to get the sum of `Total`?`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot calculate `GrandTotal` on an individual item. You need to do it on the collection of items. The property does not make sense on an individual item, and should be removed.

C# provides an easy way of computing the total:

```
var grandTotal = Items.Sum(item => item.Total);
```

If you need to explse a class that has `GrandTotal` property, wrap a list in a custom class, and put the property on the `ItemPropertiesList` class.

Answer (score 1):

Total is not an `IEnumerable` (such as a List).  It doesn't make sense to try to provide a GrandTotal property on a single Item right?  What you probably want here is a way to get a GrandTotal for a `List<ItemProperties>`, which you would use code very similar to what you have:

```
List<ItemProperties> ListOfItems = new List<ItemProperties>();
// fill the list
int sum;

foreach (ItemProperties ip in ListOfItems)
{
    sum += ip.Total;
}
```

You could also use LINQ to do this in place of an explicit foreach loop:

```
int sum = ListOfItems.Sum(x => x.Total);
```